# Multiple app entries in my MSIDatabase

Tags: wix, wix3.5

While testing my wixxml scripts, I accidentally ended up creating multiple entries in Add/Remove Progs!

For example:

- Example Demo App
- Example Demo App
- Example Demo App

Is there any simple solution to get rid of these entries? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Programs information in Control Panel is stored in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

Each product has it's own key which is either a GUID or an actual product name. You can try finding your products and deleting their keys.

You can also use the Microsoft troubleshooter: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651/

Answer (score 0):

Look in your MSI cache at `%WINDIR%\Installer`. The latest msi files should be copies of your experiments.

Use the MSIEXEC command line parameters to uninstall the old remainders.